# making login screen by using asp.net mvc 4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
  using (ReetaEntities dc = new ReetaEntities())
  {
    var v = dc.User.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(u.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (v != null)
    {
      Session["LogedUserID"] = v.UserId.ToString();
      Session["LogedUserName"] = v.Name.ToString();
      return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
    }
  }
}
return View(u);
```

> Error  3   'Entity.user' does not contain a definition for 'UserName' and no extension method 'UserName' accepting a first argument of type 'Entity.user' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Rita\Entity\Entity\Controllers\HomeController.cs 46  68  Entity
>   Error   2   'Entity.ReetaEntities' does not contain a definition for 'User' and no extension method 'User' accepting a first argument of type 'Entity.ReetaEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\Rita\Entity\Entity\Controllers\HomeController.cs 46  32  Entity
>   Error   1   'Entity.ReetaEntities' does not contain a definition for 'user' and no extension method 'user' accepting a first argument of type 'Entity.ReetaEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\Rita\Entity\Entity\Controllers\HomeController.cs 46  33  Entity

Comment: What error? Include the details.

Comment: show the code for `ReetaEntities`, since this is the class that is throwing the error....

Comment: Hi Claies the above problem is sorted out,i even manage to run successfully login page but it is accepting any username and password so there is no security how do I validate that

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your issue.  If you believe your solution would be helpful to others, I would encourage you to post an answer (self answers are acceptable here).  If you have a different question about your code now that you are no longer receiving errors, you should consider opening a new question.  Good Luck!